# Sorting many Text boxes in a form

Tags: forms, gui-design

I was wondering what to do regarding a form I have that's looking pretty messy and complicated.

There quite a few elements in it and it just looks bad... I removed the labels:

[image: Awful form]

I feel one of the ways to go would be to standardize the text box size and organize by column? I don't really know, I don't like the idea of a date input having the same size of an address field... So I would appreciate any suggestion.

**--------------- EDIT -----------------**

Here's the form with the labels back.

[image: Labels back]

Comment: Do you really have to have all of those fields?? As much as you try to pretty it up it will still be overwhelming with that many inputs.

Comment: Without usage context there is absolutely no way to answer this. Your image looks chaotic, but it might actually do exactly what it should, and in the most efficient way for the user's work flow. We don't know. You're basically asked us to organize 50+ UI elements without knowing a single thing about the system or the user.

Comment: I guarantee this can be improved dramatically. You'll need to provide a lot more info before I can help...

Comment: I think first you should bring the labels back so we can get context and they'll likely be there in the end design so might as well design for them now.

Comment: @DasBeasto I have a client whose app is all about the data, and they have dozens and dozens of text boxes and drop-downs, all of which are necessary at least *occasionally*. They key was to analyse use server-log data and the customer's data records, in order to decide on the frequency-commonality, and then reduce the *impression* of complexity by hiding most of them when a form first opens.

Comment: If you have the time, have a look at [**Web Form Design**](http://www.lukew.com/resources/web_form_design.asp) by Luke Wroblewski. It's basically a whole book about this problem. It's also concise and well-written.

Comment: I added an image with the labels back, by popular demand.

Comment: @Nelson Much better to answer with the labels! I like Jerome's answer in general but my 2 cents for specific changes are consolidate Name into 1 field and parse server side. Change Address to 1-2 fields 5 seems like way too many. 'Left Date' can be hidden and shown when 'Active' deselected. Liability seems grouped well enough to move to separate step/page. 'Age' can be removed, do the math from 'Birth Day' server side.  "contributions for year" and "create records for year" can be combined to use same year picker. I'll let someone else try to answer better though.

Comment: well, I think Jerome's answer covers it all, the only thing I'd to add to his great answer, specially after seeing the labels in your form (what a mess!) is to consider multi-step forms. Also, it doesn't look like the user has to fill all those fields, it looks like a mix of user and admin flow. Quite honestly, this is probably the most confusing form I have ever seen, you should really work this out

Comment: I don't agree that this question is too broad. It is the question of a novice, certainly. The challenge that novices face: a) they don't know the jargon or the methods, b) they don't know the relative importance of things, so c) they have difficulty formulating a question. This "Where do I start" question—and the member's recognition that there's a problem—deserves some sort of professional answer, in my opinion.

Comment: I worked on it for a bit and I manage to make it a bit better (I think) thaks for the suggestions: http://s9.postimg.org/9xzycdqcv/Capture.png | http://s15.postimg.org/aex0nbsdn/Capture2.png Its still work in progress but the "slider" cleaned the form a lot, so people not needing to edit personal details can have a digest version of the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few ideas.

#### Reduce

I'd like to +1 the comment by @DasBeasto: are all of the controls in your form truly necessary? It's entirely possible they are all necessary, but you may also be able to get rid of some edge cases. *Put yourself on a UI diet!*

Does the product need to be everything to every user on every use, or can you cater to all the most common needs, 80% of the time? This may be a **product-management decision** more than a user-experience decision. See my remarks below on usage data.

#### Grouping

This illustration shows strong grouping (left) and weak grouping (right):

[image: Grouping]

Background shading is one way to show grouping, which helps provide a sense of order to the complexity. In the above illustration, the left side clearly shows two groups.

**Be cautious with colour**

Be careful with coloured borders and coloured backgrounds, as shown in your illustration. Users won't know what each colour means, but they will assume that it's intended to convey something more than just grouping. It may increase confusion. It may also increase the impression of visual clutter.

#### Headings

The illustrations above and below all show the use of headings to add structure This helps users to scan and skip through the form, since it's clearer where one "section" begins. Organise the sections into groups that make sense to the user. In the illustration below left, the "headings" are also links that trigger the expanding-collapsing action.

#### Progressive disclosure

This illustration shows progressive disclosure (left) versus all controls (right):

[image: Progressive disclosure]

Collapsing and expanding is one way to progressively disclose (show it when it's needed; hide it when it's not), which helps visually reduce or simplify the complexity.

There are many ways to show and handle progressively disclosure, including **glyphs**, **accordions**, **tabs**, which are in place, as well as **navigating** to other pages, **pop-ups**, and so on. If you opt for in-place progressive disclosure, be sure to [use the correct glyphs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742409(v=vs.85).aspx) that are standard for the platform or operating system.

#### Check the usage data

Depending on where the results of the form are saved, and depending on how the form is delivered, you may be able to check the server log and check the actual users' data records to determine the frequency and commonality of each control's usage. In plainer language, this means *determine how often each control is used*:

- **How often** — every time the form is used? or only sometimes?
- **By how many** — by most users? or only by some users?

Controls that are used less can be buried. You can bury them by different degrees, using progressive disclosure, or even nested progressive disclosure. (Yes, some of this stinks, but when you have as many controls as you have, it's a question of how to compromise.)

Comment: It's hard to say as the question stands, but you might be on the right track with the progressive approach. Rather than expanders, paging or a wizard might be better.

Comment: Thanks. How about an up-vote to counter the negative ones? Currently I'm at -2 for this answer. :P

Comment: This is a good generic answer for various technique to help declutter a form. I'm very lost as to why it's down voted.

Comment: @Nightning it's probably my own fault, Initially I wrote part of the answer, and that I was "going in search of illustrations, BRB." I guess people didn't like a half-completed answer.

Comment: @JeromeR Ah I see. =P I believe SE auto saves drafts of your answer. So you can always come back and finish it.

Comment: Looks like your reputation has been cleared  (^‿- )